# Make changes to the base style dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to over ride the base style property but at run time.
For e.g. I have a settings page, where I allow the user to change the font size and font family etc. All these are common properties. So, I have a structure where I have defined all these basic properties. Now when I change the font size from 11px to 14px, all the elements in the application should inherit this change.

Problem is that I can't modify the base style which stores all the properties.

Below code shows my base style:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="11px"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Now I have another style which inherits from this base style:

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
       <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>
 </Style>
```

And in the application I have a combo box for font size change:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox2" SelectedValue="FontSizeValue" Style="{x:Null}" Width="92">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="12px"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="13px"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="14px"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="15px"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Now when I select a value from this combo box in the application, I will have to update the base style. Which I am not being able to do. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this. All the property changes are supposed to happen dynamically.

Comment: MSDN says: Once a style has been applied, it is sealed and cannot be changed. If you want to dynamically change a style that has already been applied, you must create a new style to replace the existing one.

Comment: Yes. Thats the problem I am facing now. Cant we get any work around for the same? I mean if i change only property of font size and some 10 other properties are to be maintained as it is, then creating a new style and updating it will override the current style and i ll lose all the default values rite? So any other work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic style should be the values that will not change for this type of control. The values that need to be changed are specified in a separate style, which can inherit the base. Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Main style for all controls -->
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    </Style>

    <!-- This style inherits all the settings from the base style, but set the background -->
    <Style x:Key="DefaultBaseStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Style>

    <!-- This style inherits only the width and height -->
    <Style x:Key="NotDefaultBaseStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource DefaultBaseStyle}" Text="Default base style" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NotDefaultBaseStyle}" Text="Not default base style" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`Output`

[image]

If you have a lot of different types of controls, then perhaps it is better to create a basic style for each of them by selecting something in common (eg: width, height, alignment). For example, the base style for the `Button`, `TextBox`, etc. And they controls that greatly different from the base, you should create a separate style that inherits the base.

**`EDIT:`**

If you want to base the style changed depending on the user's choice, then you need to create a settings with these parameters. So, go into the settings of the project:

`Project -> Properties -> Parameters`

Create a setting with name `MyColor`, type of string. To associate with the style of the setting, you need to write the following:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:DynamicStyleHelp.Properties"

<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=MyColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now setter refers to the value in the settings. Change property behind code:

```
// your namespace.Properties.Settings.Default.your name of property
DynamicStyleHelp.Properties.Settings.Default.MyColor = "Red";
```

Below is a complete example:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicStyleHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:DynamicStyleHelp.Properties"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11px" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=MyColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DefaultBaseStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="NotDefaultBaseStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource DefaultBaseStyle}" Text="Default base style" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NotDefaultBaseStyle}" Text="Not default base style" Margin="0,10,0,0" />

        <Button Name="ChangeButton" Width="100" Height="30" Content="ChangeButton" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="ChangeButton_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChangeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DynamicStyleHelp.Properties.Settings.Default.MyColor = "Red";
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to achieve this on some button click or some event on the UI. Is that possible? I have seen some bindings that can be done on the setter value. But I'm unable to understand how to use them.

Comment: @Deeksha: Could you write in detail what you need. What to do with the style by event?

Comment: I have editted my question. Please check. I hope it is little better clear. My problem is to achieve updating the styles dynamically which can include changing the base style itself. So I kwn of a method to do binding on the value of the setter property. But I am unable to understand how to use it.