# WPF override declared style in vb.net

Tags: wpf, styles, foreground

I've declared the below style. How can I override the style foreground color dynamically in my vb.net?

```
<Style x:Key="LabelWinner" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF000000" ShadowDepth="6" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFF0000"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: why do you want to override it in code behind. why dont you try trigger within style itself?

Comment: actually, when someone win the game, i want to override the foreground color according to the color that choose by the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment `@nit`, In WPF have a powerful system behavior properties in the form of `Style.Triggers`.

Earlier, in `WinForms` to change a specific property, we had to do it through the code that was not quite comfortable and practical. The developers of WPF decided to separate the visual logic related to the appearance of the program, and business logic, which contains the desired behavior of the program. Actually, it was a `Style`.

To set the `Style` trigger, you need to select the appropriate properties. The trigger is as follows:

```
<Trigger Property="SomeProperty" Value="SomeValue">

... Some actions by way of setters...

</Trigger>
```

For example, we want to see, when you hover the mouse cursor changes `Foreground` color and `FontSize`. Then we choose the property `IsMouseOver`, and then write a `Trigger`:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelWinner" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF000000" ShadowDepth="6" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It should be remembered, that in WPF have a list of value precedence ([`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)), that the local value of a higher priority than the trigger style. Therefore, if you value for property of `Label` will be set locally, the trigger will not be able to change it, for example:

```
<Label Foreground="Red" ... /> <!-- Trigger don't change foreground -->
```

If the standard property are missing, or the need to implement your scenario, then it have the attached dependency property ([`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)). Inside it, you can set any condition, for example to start the animation and the trigger in the style it will work.

Example of trigger with attached dependency property:

```
<Trigger Property="local:YourClass.MyProperty" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="SaveButton" Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I thought the xaml work like the asp.net whereby we can actually reuse / replace the <style> in aspx.vb

Comment: @user2711132: Can you describe exactly what you have, and what do you want? This can add in your question.

Comment: actually, when someone win the game, i want to override the foreground color according to the color that choose by the player. I've defaulted it to Red color, but if player choosen blue color, then i would like override the setter property to blue. If there is no shortcut, I guess I've to manually override all my labels to become blue by using their property name.

Comment: @user2711132: I think you may be suitable the dynamic resource, or work with the settings. Please see examples in my answers: [`settings1`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306572/make-changes-to-the-base-style-dynamically/18307040#18307040), [`settings2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193207/saving-user-color-settings-of-a-clicked-button/18193580#18193580), [`dynamic resources`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502467/set-control-background-color-using-dynamic-resource-in-wpf/17502941#17502941). All examples in `C#`, but I think in this case it is not critical.